# How to motion capture animations?

Tags: animation

I'm not an animation artist and so I want to create some animations for testing.
I want to use a camcorder to record me while I'm running and so
I want to know if exists a software that grab the video and translate it
in animation frames.

Comment: search Motion Capture

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you need to learn about MOCAP - Motion Capture, unless you know how to work with animation rigs etc. you wont have any good from those models.

Proffesional MOCAP studio is **money consuming**, it requires a green screens, special suits, actors, camera operators and huge ammounts of Gigabytes for storing all the date collected, which must be later processed by large workstations.

> http://www.xsens.com/en/general

[image]

For my studio, I bought a Xbox Kinect sensor which can be used to create 3d point clouds in real time, which can be later converted into animations or 3d meshes (cheap 3d scanner). It works the way that it sends thousands of small points, not visable to the eyes that are later tracked by the sensor. From these points the camera projects a 3d point cloud which can be later transformed into meshes.

[image]

My animator is using this software, to create fast animations.

> http://ipisoft.com/

Before you actually get a Kinect, for these $150, you should try to borrow it from someone, and see how the software works on your pc. It literally eats 30mb of disk space per second + something must process this, a dual core pc wont handle this.

As for the cam recorder, I wouldn't even search for such stuff as it will generate more work than it can save.

**Keep in mind, that even if you get a kinect or any other mocap device you still need to know how to process it, and the process is just the same as creating raw animations... Or get premade animations for *free* http://www.mixamo.com/motions**